# Prove: $(X_{n}-X)^{2}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}0$ then $X_{n}^{2}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}X^{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables

I'm not sure if my solution is okay. $(X_{n}-X)^{2}=(X_{n}-X)\cdot(X_{n}-X)$. Let's show that $(X_{n}-X)\xrightarrow{\text{P}}0$. Let's assume the opposite, i.e. $(X_{n}-X)\xrightarrow{\text{P}}Y, Y\neq0$. It follows from that $(X_{n}-X)\cdot(X_{n}-X)=(X_{n}-X)^{2}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}Y^{2}, Y^{2}\neq0$. Contradiction. Therefore, $(X_{n}-X)\xrightarrow{\text{P}}0$ and then we have:$$X_{n}=(X_{n}-X+X)\xrightarrow{\text{P}}0+X=X.$$ According to that we have $X_{n}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}X$ and $X_{n}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}X$ which implies $X_{n}^{2}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}X^{2}.$ Every comment is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Logically wrong. Opposite of  $(X_{n}-X)\xrightarrow{\text{P}}0$ is not $(X_{n}-X)\xrightarrow{\text{P}}Y, Y\neq0$

Comment: By $P(|X_n-X|^2>\varepsilon^2)=P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)$ then $X_n\to^P X$ and by continuous mapping we conclude.

Comment: @Snoop thanks a lot :)